# Odoo- How to add multiple views using one class

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am using Odoo 10-e. I created a custom class for order

```
class Order(models.Model):
    _name = 'amgl.order'
    _description = 'Use this class to maintain all transaction in system.'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name',readonly=True)
    order_line = fields.One2many('amgl.order_line', 'order_id', string='Order Lines')
    total_qty = fields.Float(string='Total Expected')
    total_received_qty = fields.Float(string='Total Received Quantity')
    customer_id = fields.Many2one('amgl.customer', string='Customers', required=True)
    is_pending = fields.Boolean()
    date_opened = fields.Datetime('Date Opened', required=True)
    date_received = fields.Datetime('Date Received')
```

I also created a view for this class which show all records in tree view . Now i want to create another view named 'Pending Orders' in which i want to show all order where `is_pending` is true. I am new maybe that's why i am unable to find any example in Odoo Code base.

Comment: don't add the domain to the form but add to ir.act_window (action)

Comment: Yes @CherifOdoo you are right this was my mistake. Its working fine now

Comment: ok greate good luck ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you don't need to create a new view just create a new menu and action and filter the records using domain.

```xml
 <record id="action2_...." model="ir.actions.act_window" >
         <field name="name"> Action Title </field>
        ....same as the first action...
          <field name="res_model">your.model</fiel>
         <field name="view_type">form</field>
         <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('is_pending', '=', True)] </field>
   </record> 

   <menuitem .....  action="action2_.." />
```

NB: action can have properties like `domain` ,`context`, `view_id`, `search_view_id`, `view_ids` ... etc best way to learn is read about them and see the code in odoo.

Comment: would that list all existing records of order by filtering them ?

Comment: did not understand what you said here the tree will contain all record that have is_pending = True.

Comment: don't create new one to test just add the the domain to the existing code to see if it work than add the new action and menu

Comment: No @Cherif its not working. All records are showing up no matter i add domain or not

Comment: sorry my friend you are doing something wrong because this is the right answer for you take a good look at your code and upgrade your module...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148938/discussion-between-ancient-and-cherif-odoo).

Comment: Thanks for answer and very short solution